# SSIS: "SQLISPackage140 cannot be found"

Tags: visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools, odp.net, odac, ssis-2017

I'm trying to run SSIS Package that Connect to Oracle via ODP.NET Managed Driver

I use following components:

- Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.5)
- SSDT 2017 (15.8.0)
- ODAC-32 Bit + ODAC-64 Bit (12.2.0.1.1)

While running Locally (on VS) I get the error:

> Failed to acquire connection 'XXX' Connection may not be configured
>   correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this
>   connection.

Of course I checked the connection during its setup and it is valid with the message
`Test connection succeeded`.

I checked in Event Viewer and this is the error he throws:

> The description for Event ID
>   12291 from source SQLISPackage140 cannot be found. Either the
>   component that raises this event is not installed on your local
>   computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair
>   the component on the local computer.
>   If the event originated on another computer, the display information
>   had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> Package
>
> The request is not supported

Comment: Is the package created and deployed on the same computer?

Comment: @Ulug Toprak yes

Comment: I think whats displayed in the event viewer is related to cridential miss match shown in the connection error. you could try to add the password manually as described in [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ffc53116-be4e-497a-9aff-c95c5eafa92b/re-how-to-store-sql-username-and-password-into-configruation-table?forum=sqlintegrationservices)